# HTML open new window on image onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a single image in my web page, this image is basically an architecture diagram and I need to open a new window every time someone clicks this image with different content in the new opened window based on which component of the architecture diagram has been clicked by the user. How can I best achieve this feature? Please help as I am new to this.

Comment: use `target="details"` on your `<img` tag.  Note that you have no control over whether it will open in a new window or a new tab.

Comment: You can use window.open('url')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and define [area tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) within it. This is the best way I can think of to support an image with multiple regions within it.

Comment: Thanks @Nick for the answer. I did not know about image map. Will delve deeper into it and figure it out. Thanks

Comment: No problem @CodeWithPride. If you need more examples I'm happy to pad out this answer with them... but the W3 schools examples are pretty good.

Comment: yes the W3S site is pretty decent for examples, also i found some online help for creating image maps, calculating image coordinates was tedious so i though to use online help. One query, the coordinates mentioned in the image map has to be WRT that particular image right, irrespective of its position on the webpage?

Comment: Yes they should be defined as shapes within area elements using co-ordinates respective of the image you are mapping.

Comment: '<img src="/home/suraj/image1.png" usemap="#imap">
<map name="imap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="95,135,265,280" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
</map>'  @Nick this is the code i have written.. the google webpage opens in a new tab.. but i need it to be a separate window.. is there anyway i can do that. Can i use onclick event? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank">Link text </a>
```

If you are using an image map for the links, just set the target to be _blank for each.

On a different note, do you have to open in a new window? It's just this will break the natural navigation of a browser and render the back button useless. Ending up with many new open tabs is more confusing and can be a bad user experience. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, yes opening a new window is a specific requirement, I understand it can be cumbersome but such is the requirement. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make an image map. You can do this by hand or via online tools (just Google around, [this](http://www.image-maps.com/) is the first one I found). For your links use `target="_blank"` and it will open a new window/tab.

Comment: Thanks @Peter , will look into using image map, i wasnt aware of it before. I am new to UI. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using *map* tag, i think it's easier than JavaScript

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp